# Large CSV file processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, audio

probably this may be duplicate question. I had searched lot but didn't found the answer.

I am working with audio analysis where a main audio file need to be broken down into chunks of audio files where each should of a single sentence.

When I took ~3 seconds audio for which the process I am doing is taking around 5 minutes, But taking a bigger audio length the time required to complete the process is getting much higher. for example a 5 minutes audio is taking ~14 hours. 
What I did first I created a csv file containing time(in seconds) vs Amplitude, then took a threshold where the amplitude less than *i* will be 0 and greater will be 1. Later I check if the number of consecutive 0 is greater than another threshold *j* then took the time of that position. Hence, I found the time of end of sentence. 
This process taking too long so any other methods will be helpfull.

My Dataset is as follows:

```
1.000000000000000000e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,6.103515625000000000e+01
2.000000000000000000e+00,2.267999999999999969e-05,3.051757811999999959e+01
3.000000000000000000e+00,4.534999999999999779e-05,0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00,6.802999999999999748e-05,3.051757811999999959e+01
5.000000000000000000e+00,9.069999999999999558e-05,3.051757811999999959e+01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.133800000000000020e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.360500000000000001e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.587299999999999931e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.814100000000000131e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+01,2.040800000000000112e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
1.100000000000000000e+01,2.267600000000000041e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
1.200000000000000000e+01,2.494299999999999751e-04,3.051757811999999959e+01
1.300000000000000000e+01,2.721099999999999951e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
1.400000000000000000e+01,2.947800000000000203e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
1.500000000000000000e+01,3.174599999999999861e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
1.600000000000000000e+01,3.401400000000000061e-04,3.051757811999999959e+01
1.700000000000000000e+01,3.628099999999999771e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
1.800000000000000000e+01,3.854899999999999972e-04,3.051757811999999959e+01
1.900000000000000000e+01,4.081600000000000224e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+01,4.308399999999999882e-04,0.000000000000000000e+00
2.100000000000000000e+01,4.535100000000000134e-04,3.051757811999999959e+01
```

Copyied from CSV file. The number of rows are 415449. I have given you only 20. What I required is to check first column is in (1,2,3,..., n) or not. When the series breaks I need to take the value of column 2 at the last number of series.  Hopefully I am able to clear my problems

Please note: I need to do hard-code in shell, python, C, C++.

Comment: Please explain why down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I don't see a question here nor do I understand your requirement. You might want to rewrite that question and maybe post some sample data with the expected output (of the csv in question as the title implies).

Comment: I asked for possible solutions and I mentioned my procedure. Really a sample data is required for that? It is of 4600000 lines in csv

Comment: @JamesBrown It will be helpful if you could provide your mail where I can send the data and my code and explain over there.

Comment: I am quite sure he doesn't want the data that way :) Which are the bottlenecks that you have identified? CPU, RAM, HDD read/write ?

Comment: In my process I am reading line by line of csv file which is taking much time. ANy other solution for which getting the number of consecutive value 0 at a whole will be helpful

Comment: Would still need sample data (not the 4 million lines of course) and what you tried so far (your code). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sample data and code can't be shared here. Requested to provide mail where I can send

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand you a bit, using awk for it:

```
awk -v n=6 '            # n as parameter
BEGIN { 
    FS=","              # comma as the field separator
} 
int($1)==$1 && $1<=n {  # if $1 is an integer less than or equal to n
    val=$2              # value of column 2 at the last number of series
}
END {
    print val           # output the value
}' file
1.133800000000000020e-04
```

**Update**:

```
$ awk -v i=1 -v j=0 -v k=3 '
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}
$3<i {        # if the value of 3rd column is less than "i" 
    j++       # then "j" will increment by 1
}
j>k {         # when the value of "j" is greater than a value "k" 
    print $1  # It will print the column 1 value
    # exit    # uncomment this if it only needs to print one value
}' file
8.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+01
1.100000000000000000e+01
1.200000000000000000e+01
...
```

Comment: Thanks @James It works I need to slightly change. I will ask for help if required. For information I am working in "Video Surveillance".

Comment: The more accurate the requirement, the better the code.

Comment: Suppose , I will check the 3rd column row by row by if the value of 3rd column is less than "i" then "j" will increment by 1. And when the value of "j" is greater than a value "k" It will print the column 1 value.